# Protractor: How do I click on an element using the href substring or span substring?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, protractor, href

The following lines is information of the element I want to be able to click on using protractor.

```
    <hsx-nav-menu-group hsx-html-element> == $0
      <hsx-nav-menu-info>
        <i hsx-html-element hsx-icon>
          <svg>
            <use xlink:href="#icon-so"></use>
          </svg>
        </i>
        <span>Service Orders</span>
      </hsx-nav-menu-info>
    </div>
```

I have been able to click on it via the xpath but I wanted to locate and click the element preferably with the href substring or the span subtring.

Comment: Doesn't look like Protractor supports this: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/456

Comment: I was on that site earlier. I realize these locators aren't supported but I was wondering would these be able to work with the addLocator() function?I have tried it but it wouldn't work. Could you see any reason for why it wouldn't work besides the fact that I may have created incorrect implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to locate and click the element preferably with the href substring or the span subtring

Let's use the `Service Orders` text to create a locator:

```
element(by.xpath("//hsx-nav-menu-info[span = 'Service Orders']"));
```

This is still an XPath expression though.

---

Alternatively, you can use [`filter()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
$$("hsx-nav-menu-info").filter(function (useElm) {
    return useElm.$("use").getAttribute("xlink:href").then(function (href) {
        return href === "#icon-so";
    });
}).first().click();
```

Comment: Thank you. I mainly wanted a way to locate the element using the text "#icon-so" for the href in the <use> locator because I am working with other elements with similar locators but more of them have a  <use> locator than the <span>.

Comment: @J.Chang gotcha, updated the answer with an alternative option, please check.

Comment: With that I am currently getting an error saying
"Failed: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (13, 438). Other element would receive the click: <svg>...</svg>."